# Fresh install Windows10 - best option?

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-10

I'll have to fresh install Win10. Not just the reinstall option of Win10 which keeps all the drivers, files and settings, but a total clean install.

Whats the best way to do that and have all the drivers be installed again automaticly?

Its just a pity to having to install all the drivers manually again.

Comment: use the Reset Feature in settings app, here you can wipe Windows and this is the same like clean install. drivers come via WindowsUpdate

Comment: You have 2 options.  Reset feature and choose not to keep anything, or install Windows 10 again and choose not to keep anything, both result in identical system states.

Answer (score -1):

There's a big change that Windows 10 would automatically download and install the missing drivers and Windows 10 will notify you about that. This thing happened to me when I've done a total clean install of Windows 10. 
Generally it could be possible if there's a good connection to the internet.

I hope this would help you!

Comment: This seems more like a comment.  Comments should only be submitted to the comment section.  If you are unable to post comments to the comments section, because of the lack of reputation in order to do so, the comments shouldn't be submitted.